# How can I cycle a multidimensional array and load one part at a time? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, performance, loading

I have a very very big multidimensional javascript array object with coordinates of many earthquakes.

Like this:

```
var array_eq= [
            [
            0 : {
              "casa": "home",
              "lat": "30",
              "lng": "40"
              },
            //...//
            400 : {
              "casa": "home",
              "lat": "30",
              "lng": "40"
              }
            ],
           [
            0 : {
              "casa": "home",
              "lat": "30",
              "lng": "40"
              },
            //...//
            400 : {
              "casa": "home",
              "lat": "30",
              "lng": "40"
              }
            ]
           ];
```

So each "array container" contains 400 earthquakes.
All the array can have more than 120.000 earthquakes....

It takes a long time to show all in `google maps` so I tried to show earthquakes in the "array container" (so every 400) one by one.

I tried to loop array in this way:

```
 for(var f= 0; f < array_eq.length; f++){   
    for(var i= 0; i < array_eq[f].length; i++){ 
     //add erathquakes/markers on google maps
    }
 }
```

but there does not seem to be a block loading, this way all earthquakes in the array are loaded together.
This way it is too long for the user ....

Can you give me some advice?

Could I  solve this problem using `ajax` ?

Comment: So you have 400 x 120,000 items and you want to add a marker for each? That’s 48 million markers.

Comment: nono are 120,000 earthquakes divided in 400 parts. In database are 1.700.000 earthquakes and, theoretically, an user could be show all these quakes.

Answer (score -4):

One option is to create a function for filter control. I have updated JSFiddle with a possible solution. For example, I set a filterTurma () function like this:

```
$ scope.filterTurma = function (user) {

// If the value is be !! '(value you are assigning to' Everyone '),
// just returned 'true' for all cases to continue showing up ...
if ($ scope.search_turma.turmas.value == '!!')
true return;

// Do the opposite, do the classes of the user, and verify that at least
// one suites matches an advanced class in the combobox ...
for (var i = 0; i <user.turma.length; i ++) {
var class = user.turmas [i];
if (turma.value == $ scope.search_turma.turma.value)
true return;
}

// if it matched, return 'false' to hide this user ...
returns false;
};
```

Summarizing the code, in your combo you have as classes, and still an option "Everyone" with the value '!!'. No filter, just check if the current value of the item is selected in the combobox is this, otherwise we check if at least one class corresponds to the selected class. In your HTML, to apply this filter, just do so:

```
tr ng-repeat = "user in dataUserAndTurma | filter: {name: search_nome} | filter: filterTurma"
```

Note that I do not use parentheses in the name of the method (the angularjs willenter code here automatically pass the current user in iteration to the method), in addition I kept the original filter, ie the filters complement each other).

Comment: Are you sure your answer is in a right question? i don't understand your code and how can help me...

Comment: Meu código foi feito agora para o exemplo,oque eu quero que faça é se basear.

Comment: Aplicar no seu caso usando o mesmo modelo de estrutura que montei nessa função.

Comment: This "answer" has absolutely nothing to do with the question. There is not even any Angular involved. Also, `true return;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Okay, sorry for trying to help, I did not interpret the question correctly then..